# JQuery Max Num + Randomization

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function maxStyle() {
    var one = parseInt($("#num-one"));
    var two = parseInt($("#num-two"));
    var three = parseInt($("#num-three"));
}
```

1. Find the largest number and +1 to its variable.
2. If there are multiple variables that are equal to the max, randomly choose one of the variables, and +1 to it.

I know that I can use Math.max() - but that just returns a number so how do I get the variable?

Sorry for noobishness in advance, I've only spent 4 days with JS/JQ.

Comment: The functionality you're describing sounds straightforward if we're talking about just numbers. I don't understand how you're using jQuery-selected objects here. Could you provide the HTML you'd have going with this? What attribute of the selected elements are you reading and changing?

Comment: Instead of answering, I'd point you to [JavaScript Basics](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/zZpVq/1/

```
var max = -Infinity; // variable to store max value;

var maxEle = $(".num").each(function() {
    if (+this.value > max) max = +this.value;  // find the max value
}).filter(function() {
    return this.value == max;  // filter elements to ones that share max value
});

if (maxEle.length > 1)   // get a random element with the max value
    maxEle = maxEle.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * maxEle.length));

maxEle.css("border-color", "red");​ // do something with that element.
```

Edit — Changed initial `max` to `-Infinity` and forced a numeric conversion of `this.value` with unary plus so this will work with negative values as well.

Comment: If you hit run multiple times, you can see that it will change between the three inputs that share the max value;

Comment: What if .num's were dic's see my interpretation of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/DyGqm/12/

Comment: Thanks! I hope I get better at this right now in my first week I admit I am a little confused.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
function maxStyle() {
    var one = parseInt($("#num-one").val()),
        two = parseInt($("#num-two").val()),
        three = parseInt($("#num-three").val()),
        four = parseInt($("#num-three").val()),
        five = parseInt($("#num-three").val());
        // ..etc.

    var arr = [one, two, three, four, five /*, etc. */],
        tempArr = [];

    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (b - a)
    }); // now array is sorted with highest element on top

    arr[0] = arr[0] + 1; // increment the highest element by 1, per question

    var a = 0, b;
    for (b = 0; b < arr.length; b++ ) {
        if(arr[a] == arr[b]) {
            tempArr.push(arr[b]);
            a++; 
            // not incrementing outside the loop, 
            // since we don't want to compare other duplicates, 
            // but only the largest which is the first element
        }
    }

    // We now have an array of multiple items equal to the max
```

> If there are multiple variables that are equal to the max, randomly
>   choose one of the variables, and +1 to it.

```
    // Continue Code..
    // Generate a random between 1 and no. of items
    randomItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length) + 1;
    tempArr[randomItem] = tempArr[randomItem] + 1;

    return arr[0] > tempArr[randomItem] ? arr[0] : tempArr[randomItem];
}
```

Comment: This returns the value of the highest variable, do you know how to return the actual div or somehow change the css of the actual div, thanks. Apart from that, it's an excellent solution.

Comment: to get the actual `div` with the `number`, use `var myEl = $('div').eq(number)`, where `number` is what we got from maxStyle. Then to add css, in the same function `maxStyle` use `myEl.css('property', 'value')`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking to do...

```
function maxStyle() {
  var one = parseInt($("#num-one").val());
  var two = parseInt($("#num-two").val());
  var three = parseInt($("#num-three").val());
  var maxed = Math.max(one, Math.max(two, three)) + 1; // Max of all three plus 1
}
```

The variable `maxed` will have the value of whatever the is the maximum of the three inputs... Presuming they are inputs.

I'm not sure where the randomization comes into it (from your question title).

Comment: RANDOMIZATION - "If there are multiple variables that are equal to the max, randomly choose one of the variables, and +1 to it."

Answer (score 0):

First issue

```
parseInt($("#num-one"));
```

How are you getting a number from a jQuery object?

You should be using .val() or .text()

```
parseInt($("#num-one").val(),10);
```

And when you use parseInt, use a radix.

Now for the other issues, you would need to use some if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I would just set up an array of all the ids and compare them to a stored maximum value.

```
var idArr = ['#num-one', '#num-two', '#num-three'];

function maxNum(idArr) {
  var max = 0;
  $.each( idArr, function( key, value ) {
    var curr = parseInt($(value).val(),10);
    if (curr > max) max = curr;
  });
  return max+1;
}

alert('Max :' + maxNum(idArr));
```